# Extract Inner Nodes from XML string to a JSON string

Tags: c#, json, xml

```
string inputxml = "<transaction>
<node1>value1</node1>
<node2>value2</node2>
<node3>value3</node3>
</transaction>"
```

I want to convert this XML string to JSON string in the below format after omitting the outermost  node:

```
{"node1";"value1","node2":"value2","node3":"value3"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

1 - [**XDocument**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netcore-3.1) to build anonymous object that match the Json like :

```
string inputxml = @"<transaction>
                        <node1>value1</node1>
                        <node2>value2</node2>
                        <node3>value3</node3>
                    </transaction>";

var node = XDocument.Parse(inputxml)
    .Descendants("transaction")
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Node1 = x.Element("node1").Value,
        Node2 = x.Element("node2").Value,
        Node3 = x.Element("node3").Value
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

2 - [**Newtonsoft**](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) to serialize the object like :

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(node);
```

**Demo**

```
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

**Result**

```
{"Node1":"value1","Node2":"value2","Node3":"value3"}
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Beat me to it!  Nice answer.  And use of anonymous to get rid of the "outer element".

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood your problem you do not have model neither for source XML nor for JSON and names can chenge in future, so we shouldn't use strict names. So we will try to build it dynamically. Pay attention - u'll need to use Newtonsoft.Json nuget pack.

```
string inputxml = @"<transaction>
<node1>value1</node1>
<node2>value2</node2>
<node3>value3</node3>
</transaction>";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(inputxml); //parse XML document
var jprops = xdoc.Root.Elements() // take elements in root of the doc
    .Select(x => (x.Name, x.Value)) // map it to tuples (XName, string)
    .Select(x => new JProperty(x.Name.LocalName, x.Value)); //map it to enumerbale of Json properties
JObject resultingObj = new JObject(jprops); // construct your json and populate its contents
Console.WriteLine(resultingObj.ToString()); // Write out - u r awesome
```